# Configuring 2 NIC with 2 gateways

Tags: routing, iproute, proxmox, dmz

Lets say my router has a LAN (192.168.0.1/24) and a DMZ (192.168.1.1/24).
My computer has 2 NICs, one for LAN and one for DMZ.

How can I configure my routes so that it uses both gateways instead of a default one?

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:6f:94:44
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:458357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:250537 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:646967588 (616.9 MiB)  TX bytes:33742301 (32.1 MiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fc3e0000-fc400000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:4f:13:31:b7
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:320 (320.0 B)  TX bytes:2992 (2.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:18979 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18979 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:10059282 (9.5 MiB)  TX bytes:10059282 (9.5 MiB)

tap103i0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3e:fb:b1:e0:40:da
          inet6 addr: fe80::3cfb:b1ff:fee0:40da/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:766 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:44796 (43.7 KiB)  TX bytes:702165 (685.7 KiB)

vmbr0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:6f:94:44
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe6f:9444/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:437651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:245697 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:637230824 (607.7 MiB)  TX bytes:31203868 (29.7 MiB)

vmbr1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:4f:13:31:b7
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:4fff:fe13:31b7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:230 (230.0 B)  TX bytes:2412 (2.3 KiB)
```

Output of `netstat -rn`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 vmbr0
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 vmbr0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmbr0
192.168.1.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 vmbr1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmbr1
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        post-up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1


auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.2
        bridge_ports eth1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        post-up route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using 2 gateways?  are you trying to load balance traffic across both nics?  are you wanting to pass local traffic to the lan, and non-local traffic through the DMZ?

Comment: I'm trying to have DMZ facing VMs and internal VMs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're needing it to use different default routes based on which local IP address is being used, this is where iproute2 comes into play.

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and add this line to each network interface stanza/block to define the static routes

```
# this is for vmbr0 block below
post-up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1

# this is for vmbr1 block below
post-up route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

and you need to restart networking subsytem/service by `service networking restart`

**OR**

You can change the routing dynamically, but you will lose them when you reboot. It is good for testing purposes or for short term use.

```
route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.0.1 dev vmbr0
route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 192.168.1.1 dev vmbr1
```

This does not require you to restart networking, although it might cause a momentary disruption or session losses due to network switchover, when and where necessary.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the lines in my interface and restarted networking. Routes seem to look normal now. However, `ping -I vmbr1 192.168.1.1` and `ping -I vmbr1 google.ca` both don't return anything.

Comment: what do you see as an output to `netstat -rn` command ?

Comment: `Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 vmbr0
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 vmbr0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmbr0
192.168.1.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 vmbr1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmbr1`

Comment: could you please update your original post with this information? Without the line breaks, it is very hard to follow.

Comment: Updated, I don't post here very often so I'm not very good at formatting.